# Block programs from reading outside their own allocated RAM?

Tags: windows, security

Recently I came across a software program that monitors what's exactly running in my RAM. The company actually stores this information on their servers. Obviously I feel like this is an invasion of my privacy. So I was wondering if it's somehow possible to prevent this?

I know software needs access to their own allocated RAM. But I see no reason why software should be able to look outside of the box. It's simply none of their business what I'm doing behind my pc and not.

More clerity:

I'm not talking about software being able to read inside another programs RAM. I'm talking about being able to see which programs are currently running on the machine. However I realise this is not the correct place to ask this question. So I appologize for that. I'm going to search for a better place. Thanks a lot for the help though.

Comment: Processes can modify their own access token in a way that prevents 3rd party processes without admin permission to read/write into their memory via Read/WriteProcessMeory. I have seen that once in a program as part of an anti-debugging technique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kind of security you desire is generally part of the design principles of any modern consumer OS (like Windows). Anything that works around it is intentional monitoring done with the cooperation of the administrator of the machine.

"User" programs (applications) are indeed only allowed to see "their own" RAM contents. The system, however, including kernel mode drivers, have greater visibility. It's possible the company you work for (?) has installed software on your machine as the administrator that does more peeking around. It's not clear from your question (and this isn't really the right forum) what exactly is going on, but if you don't fundamentally control the computer, you can't fundamentally control what's running in its kernel.

Comment: You're right. I knew this was probebly not the best place to ask. I just didn't know where else to go. It's not about working for a company. It's my own private computer.

It's about a game monitoring RAM for 3rd party software. This is understandable ofcourse, but I didn't like the fact that they're actually storing this information on their servers. The game is probebly unable to read inside the RAM. It is however able to see which programs are running.

Comment: @user2780711: Head over to http://superuser.com/ and ask there. If it's your own computer, then add information about what you're seeing and how you know what it's doing.

Comment: I'm marking your answer as the accepted answer because it explains how it works and you've helped me on my way to find more information.

Answer (score -1):

The operating system and the cpu's memory management unit do not allow user-level program to access memory allocated to other programs.

Either you are dealing with a kernel-level program or the program is using some kernel services.

Comment: You are wrong. There is an API in Windows which allows you to read process memory of other processes of the same user.

Comment: Robert read the complete answer. It says the program could be using a KERNEL SERVICE.